# Cordova build failed after Xcode update

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am getting this message from the terminal when running my project with the command `cordova build`. I have to say that everything was fine before today, and Xcode updated from my Mac.

I have tried everything, but without success. Any help please?

the following build commands failed:

```
Ld /Users/MYUSERNAME/documents/wander/wanderapp/platforms/ios/build/emulator/HelloWorld.app/HelloWorld normal i386 (1 failure) Error: /Users/MYUSERNAME/documents/wander/wanderapp/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 65
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Comment: You need to make sure you are on cordova 3.6 if your xcode is updated to 6

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and had to remove the platform and add it back.

```
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios
```